# Yii 2 dropdown value safe newbie

Tags: get, yii2, widget, dropdown

I heard building Data in View is not very good, but anyway, i am wondering why its not working:

**View**

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();

 $alleSpieler = \common\models\Spieler::find()->all();

 if ($alleSpieler) {
 unset($types);
 foreach ($alleSpieler as $value) {
               $types[$value->id] = $value->email . ' ' . $value->vorname . ' ' . $value->nachname;   
                              } 
                         } 

 echo $form->field($model, 'spielerId')->dropDownList($types, 'prompt'=>'Spieler manuell hinzufügen']);

                          ActiveForm::end();
                          ?>

 <?= AnmeldungDurchfuehrung2::widget(['durchfuehrungId' => $model->id, 'spielerId' => $model->spielerId]) ?>
```

**Model**

```
public $spielerId;
```

But spielerId ist not set in my Case. If i, for example, set 'spielerId' => 1120 in the widget call, it is working. But if i want the value from the dropdownlist, the action is saying that spielerId is missing. I am newbie and perhaps i forgot something? Thank you!

Comment: what do i  have to do that $spielerId is filled with the id from Dropdown?

Comment: You need to write javascript for change event of dropdown

Comment: can you help me with javascript?  is it something like this?
echo $form->field($model, 'spielerId')->dropDownList($types, array('onchange'=>'getData($model->spielerId)','class' =>'form-control','prompt'=>'-Choose a Player-'));

Answer (score 2):

You must add `$spielerId;` in validation array in your model, som like this:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['spielerId'], 'integer'], //type of atribute value
        [['spielerId'], 'required'], //if need 
        /*... other atributes ...*/
    ];
}
```

for more detail check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html).

Comment: Sorry, I wrong understanded your question, truble in the understandig of work yii2, first you need upload data in model for using them. In your case i recomendet create create separate action to render the widget after change value in spielerId field, and use $this->renderAjax function to return it.

Comment: So you need :
1) Js script witch will bee send selected value in action and handle response (insert resived content in your )
2) action in controller witch  will get data and render view: `$this->renderAjax('_sform', ['id' => $id, 'spielerId' => $spielerId]);`
3) view with content: `<?= AnmeldungDurchfuehrung2::widget(['durchfuehrungId' => $id, 'spielerId' => $spielerId]) ?>`

Comment: First thank you!
I am very bad with ajax. So perhaps i can get value from dropdown with $GET Parameter? It is no problem if user must click one more time. 

I tried with standard html form(imput field) and it works with $GET. So it must be possible that i can get my selected Value from Active Form Dropdownlist with $GET Paramter??? Im not able to find Documentation about this in Yii2 active form....

Comment: It's not good idea, but if you whant so you can use html helper for this purpose:`Html::dropDownList()` check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html), alsou for get parameters from `$_GET` use yii2 tools like this `Yii::$app->request->get('varName', 'defaultValue');` asou for more details check [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html)

Comment: Because the MVS standard has not been met, my previous offer was more complicated but more correct in terms of MVC

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the help

Answer (score 1):

okay now i know what i need:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'spielerId')->dropDownList($types,['prompt'=>'Waehlen Sie einen Spieler']); 
echo Html::submitButton('Auswählen', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```

This is my Dropdown.

**I need something like:**

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['spielerId'])) {
                      echo AnmeldungDurchfuehrung2::widget(['durchfuehrungId' => $model->id, 'spielerId' => $_GET['subject']]); }?>
```